# Studying Griffiths Intro to QM. Need help understanding how to construct free particle wave functions with non-zero momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am studying *Introduction To Quantum Mechanics* by David Griffiths. Great book.

In section $2.4$ he introduces the Free Particle potential and describes finding general solutions made up of an envelope '$\phi(k)$' and ripples 'complex exponential in $x$,$t$'

The envelope function '$\phi(k)$' is found by integrating the initial wave function '$\Psi(x,0)$'.

My question is how this method of finding solutions could ever result in a wave packet that is "moving". If $\phi(k)$ is just based on a snapshot of the wave function at $t=0$ won't that always result in solutions that just show how that stationary wave function spreads out over time?

This also seems to be the case in the examples that I have seen. Problem $2.22$ results in a wave function with momentum $= 0$.

I feel like I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: "*won't that always result in solutions that just show how that stationary wave function spreads out over time?*" Is this different from what you mean by "moving"?

Comment: In problem 2.22 the initial wave function is even—that's why momentum is zero.

Answer (score 1):

A general free-particle state takes the form

$$\psi(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) \exp[ikx]dk$$

The average momentum of this state can be shown to be
$$\left<\hat p \right> = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hbar k |\phi(k)|^2 dk$$

If the function $|\phi(k)|^2$ is even, then $\left<\hat p\right>=0$; of course, this need not be the case in general.  Consider the initial state
$$\psi(x,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp[-x^2] \cdot \exp[-ix]$$
This corresponds to $$\phi(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\frac{(k+1)^2}{4}\right]$$
which is clearly not even in $k$.  The time evolution of this state is shown below.

[image]

More generally, taking a state $\psi(x)$ and multiplying it by $e^{iqx/\hbar}$ increases the expected value of the momentum by an amount $q$; the proof is a good exercise.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very helpful. Is it correct that if the initial wavefunction is even, then momentum will be zero, or is it that phi(k) being even makes momentum zero? 

Felipe in the comments above suggested that an even initial wavefunction causes momentum to be zero, but in your example there is an even initial wavefunction, but somehow that made a noneven phi(k).

Comment: @johnconsiglio Ah, I see I've been misleading; I plotted the probability density, not the wavefunction itself.  I will correct my plot.  My wavefunction is *not* even, because it includes a complex phase factor.